# why final URL of my desktop website always linked to mobile version website (m.mywebsite) on social media share?

Tags: facebook, url, mobile, share, canonical-link

i have desktop website mywebsite.com and mobile version m.mywebsite.com.
however, when i want to add some social media share that need final url such as facebook and g+ share, the final URL always linked to my m.mywebsite.com even though i add the social media share in my desktop version website.

This is what i get when i used facebook debug tool:
original        http://mywebsite.com/
301             http://www.mywebsite.com/
302             http://m.mywebsite.com/#!/
rel="canonical" **http://m.mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=%2F**

The final URL, which facebook tried to extract metadata from is highlighted in bold

i'm only use a canonical url in my mobile version website

is there anything wrong? or anything necessary that i need to add to my code?

thank you for your response.

Comment: This smells like a user agent redirection. When the social media site 'sniffs' your link it's probably doing it with a custom user agent string that your server doesn't recognise, so your server redirects them to the mobile link.

Comment: thank you for your response. If thats true, where i have to place the code to recognize the user agent from facebook? on mobile site or desktop site? thx

Comment: OMG!!! Now it fixed!! I realized there is some stupid code that set the default redirect to mobile site on my nginx code. thank you for remind me about user agent @Skrrp.

Comment: No worries. Glad you've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

OMG!!! Now it fixed!! I realized there is some stupid code that set the default redirect to mobile site on my nginx code. thank you for remind me about user agent @Skrrp.

Comment: Hi Hanson , I am facing same issue. My desktop site is on Apache and mobile site is on Nginx. I also set canonical to desktop url for each mobile site url if its desktop version available. Can you tell me which suspected settings I can check on Apache / Nginx